# angular 2 uploading file using ng2-uploader

Tags: angular

i am new in angular 2. i am uploading file using ng2-uploder. file is uploading successfully but its showing me below error in console:

> ```
>     ERROR TypeError: _this.files.filter is not a function
>     at ng-file-select.ts:41
>     at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.es5.js:3840)
>     at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:236)
>     at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
>     at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
>     at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
>     at EventEmitter.Subject.next (Subject.js:55)
>     at EventEmitter.emit (core.es5.js:3814)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (ng2-uploader.ts:103)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (zone.js:1199)
>     at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.1218.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
>     at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4116)
>     at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.1218.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:397)
>     at Zone.webpackJsonp.1218.Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)
> ```

Comment: We can't really help you without code. My first guess would be that your `files` property isn't an Array. Try `console.log`ging it to see what exactly it is.

Answer (score 0):

Here, i got solution of my problem:

```
Instead of using ng2-uploader, i used ngx-uploader:
First install using "sudo npm add ngx-uploader" ,
then using below link as it is:
  "https://github.com/jkuri/ngx-uploader#backend-example-using-express"
   It is working perfectly for me.
```